# button is disabled but it is stil listens to click event

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium for scraping and automation.

```
while (True):
    try:
        in_the_cart=bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="product_page_detail"]/div[2]/div[10]/form/section/div/button')
        in_the_cart.click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('buttonDisabled')
        time.sleep(5)

# in_the_cart.click()
while (True):
    try:
        in_the_cart = bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="product_page_detail"]/div[2]/div[10]/form/section/div/button')
        in_the_cart.click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('buttonDisabled')
        time.sleep(5)
        break
```

This is my code. the button is disabled but it is still clicked. I need to stay on the same first loop until the button is not available

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check until the button element has attribute `enabled` or the button element does not have attribute `disabled`, only then click on the button.

In this case,

```
if(in_the_cart.get_attribute('disabled') == "None"){
 in_the_cart.click()
}
```